# How do I access two levels of data in an ExtJS 4 grid model?

Tags: extjs, model, nested, extjs4.2

Here is some sample data (its simplified, not real data):

```
objects: [
    {
        name: 'pool1',
            groups: [
                {
                    name: 'group1'
                },
                {
                    name: 'group2'
                }
          ]
    }
]
```

I have a grid that currently has a store with root of 'objects', so the above data would result in one row in the grid, because there is one object.

We instead want one row in the grid per group. So I can change the root to objects.groups.

But for each row, I also need to access data for the outside parent 'object'.

Is this possible? Or do I need new data delivered, with the groups at the top 'objects' level, and the parent data duplicated for each child group?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have given the root config in the reader of store. Add another config 'record': 'groups' and try. Look at the following sample code.

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'objects',
    record: 'groups'
}
```

--Sridhar

Comment: That sounds very promising. Thanks very much, I'll look into it and mark this the answer if it solves it.